# I want to filter data from db on price condition

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get some data from db using price range, but it display all records and might be condition not working

**my ajax call**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#price_filter").on("change", function() {
                var price = $(this) .val();
                var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:"{{ route('indexController.pricefilter') }}",
                    type:"post",
                    dataType:"html",
                    data:{price : price,_token},
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#filterdata").html(response);
                    }
                });
            })
        })  
</script>
```

**my route**

```
Route::post('indexController/pricefilter','indexController@pricefilter')->name('indexController.pricefilter');
```

**my function**

```
public function pricefilter(Request $request){
  $prod_price = $request->get('price');
       $products = DB::table('products');
        if(!empty($prod_price)){
          $products->where('price','<=', $prod_price);
         return $products->get();
    } 
     return view('pages.pricefilter')->with('products', $products);
}
```

if I select `500` it would display result equal or less than `price 500` but it also display greater than 500

**result**

```
[{"id":1,"created_at":"2020-09-24 06:35:13","updated_at":"2020-09-24 10:01:37","product_name":"dummy product 1","make":"audi","model":"A1","category":"S class","sub_category":"tyres","year":"2020","month":"9","body_type":"genuine","price":"100","available_qty":"5","colour":"blue","condition":"1","unit":"mm","shipping_cost":"50","location":"germany","pick_up_available":"0","delievery_time":"6","images":"1600929313_Capture03.JPG|1600929313_Capture04.JPG","keywords":"[{\"value\":\"ddd\"},{\"value\":\"gg\"},{\"value\":\"uuu\"}]","source":"amazon"},{"id":2,"created_at":"2020-09-24 10:23:41","updated_at":"2020-09-24 10:23:41","product_name":"dummy product 3","make":"Toyota","model":"Xli","category":"S class","sub_category":"rym","year":"2020","month":"9","body_type":"copy","price":"1000","available_qty":"10","colour":"red","condition":"1","unit":"mm","shipping_cost":"1000","location":"usa","pick_up_available":"1","delievery_time":"1","images":"1600943021_Capture06.JPG","keywords":"[{\"value\":\"ttt\"},{\"value\":\"ggg\"},{\"value\":\"gggr\"}]","source":"amazon"}]
```

if I use `DB::enableQueryLog();` `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` then `result` I think `where clause` not worling

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `products` where `price` <= ?"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "300"
    ]
    "time" => 23.92
  ]
]
```

Comment: your problem is :   return $products->get(); 
why you put this statement in your code, i recommend using @sta solution

Comment: is your price field a string? and why is it a string

Comment: I post value using dropdown

Comment: You can use ```when(request('price'), function(){$qw->where('price', '<=', request ('price'))})->get()``` ```when()``` method check if ```request('price')``` is exists

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public function pricefilter(Request $request){
  $prod_price = $request->get('price');
       $products = DB::table('products');
        if(!empty($prod_price)){
          $products->where('price','<=', $prod_price);
         } 
     $products = $products->get();
     return view('pages.pricefilter')->with('products', $products);
}
```

Comment: same issue it return all rows from `db`